# Can't send array to php via ajax and back

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to get a button on my page which will eventually be a delete button to work. However because it is a `<li>` element and not your average submit button with a form etc... i have to use ajax to send all the variables to be processed, at the moment i just want them to be in a state where they can be processed, but at the moment my script doesn't seem to return any value like i want it to and output them.

Hopefully from the code below you will see what i mean, all i need it to do at the moment is just select all the values from the checkboxes which are cehcked and send it to the mail_trash.php, and then just send it back and output the array, just so i can see it is selecting the proper values etc... The actual delete php code is already written and working, this is just to check the Ajax.

Here is the javascript and ajax

```
    <script>
        $("document").ready(function (){ 

           $("li.trash").click(function(e){  
                 var db = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(i,n) {
                    return $(n).val();
                 }).get(); //get converts it to an array

             if(db.length == 0) { 
             db = "none"; 
           }        

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "mail_trash.php",
            data: {'db[]':db  },
            dataType: "json",
            statusCode: {
                200: function (response) {
                                                                                           $("#mail_header_name").html(response.mess_id);

                                         }

            }
        });
    });

});


</script>
```

And here is the script for the mail_trash.php

```
  <?php

    include 'connect_to_mysql.php';

    $mess_id = $_GET["db"];
    echo json_encode($mess_id);


?>
```

And just to check things the

button

```
<li><a class="trash" href="">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Thank you so much for your help, this has been bugging me for the last couple of hours.

Comment: Could you add console.log(db) to your JavaScript code before Ajax call and tell what it prints to console?

Comment: Hi i tried what you said, i put it right above where it says $.ajax etc... but it didn't output anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not li.trash. It's a.trash because trash is a class of the a element. As such the first three lines of the js should be:

```
   <script>
    $("document").ready(function (){ 

       $("a.trash").click(function(e){
```

and then so on with the rest of you code. I haven't checked the rest of your code necessarily, although I am pretty iffy about $(':checkbox:checked') as I don't think that's correct jquery.... To start off, I'd suggest fixing the first selector I mentioned, checking the second with [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com) and then jshinting/jslinting your code. (Javascript only)

Comment: hi i cant believe i didn't notice that before, thankyou for your help, but changing the li to an `a` still didn't help, i will have a look again at the code

Comment: Have you tried jshint/jslint? And console? (Ctrl + Shift + J)

Comment: Btw, this could be your ajax request `$.getJSON("mail_trash.php", {'db[]':db  }, function (response) {                                                                                        $("#mail_header_name").html(response.mess_id);
});` The other thing is, do you have jQuery imported onto your webpage?

Comment: no i haven't got jquery imported, what do i need to do for that? Thanks

Comment: Hi, just thought i would let you know that i managed to solve, it after trying most of the night trying to get it to work, i opted to just put a new submit button inside the <li> element, so i can now call all the php a lot easier. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its a typo in the question itself or the issue with your script but name of th e parameter while passing is "db" but on the server side you are expecting "mess_id"

Comment: oh yeah sorry i was playing around, i will change it now, but it still does not work even when they are both db, sorry